# unable to see the updated DOM in spec after its getting modified

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, jsdom

I am writing a functional spec using Mocha/JSDOM and asserting with 'chai'.

The use case is when I call the function: updateContent,

1. It would internally call another function that would fetch some HTML content.
2. Later I would process that HTML content and add it to the existing DOM elements.

This is working fine when I run on the server but the issue is when I try to write a spec, not able to see the updated DOM. I checked the updateContent function by placing the console statement and I see the updated content but once the control transferred to the spec function, I am seeing the original DOM that is added to JSDOM.

This is written using Typescript, js combination, and JQuery for DOM operations

Could you please help me with what am I missing here? Any suggestion/info would be helpful.
I tried using global while accessing

**updateContent function available in *helper.js* file**

```
function updateContent(year, fetchAge) {
    Promise.all([fetchAge("age")]).then((data) => {
        console.log("DOM before update ="+$('html').html());
        data = data[0].replace(/{{age}}/g, year);
        $('.mybenifits .content').html(data);
        console.log("DOM after update ="+$('html').html());//Able to see the updated DOM
        console.log("$('.mybenifits .content').html="+global.$('.mybenifits .content').html());
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(" ******* Error while fetching age info");
    });
}
```

**Spec Code snippet: *helper.test.js***

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');


const { updateContent } = require('../../main/webpack/common/helper.js');

describe('Helper - Example',  () => {
    it('should update the content', () => {  
        let htmlStr = '<!doctype html><html><body><div class="mybenifits"><div class="content"></div></div></body></html>';
        const jsdom = new JSDOM(htmlStr, {
            url: 'http://localhost/',
        });
        //Setting Global variables - start
        global.window = jsdom.window;
        global.document = jsdom.window.document;
        global.$ = require('jquery');
        //Setting GLobal variables - end
        
        //Mocking fetchAge function
        function fetchAge(featurename) {
            return '<p id="fcontent">Current Age is {{age}}</p>';
        }
        updateContent("2020",fetchAge);
        console.log("Total html file ="+$('html').html());
        //expect($('.mybenifits .content').html()).to.be.equal('<p id="fcontent">Current Age is 2020</p>');
        //expect(global.$('.mybenifits .content').html()).to.be.equal('<p id="fcontent">Current Age is 2020</p>');//Not working even if I use global 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is probably because your `updateContent` function does its operations asynchronously whilst the rest of the code continues. This likely means that the `expect` assertions are being called **before** `updateContent` finishes updating the spec.

First of all, and I can not stress this enough - getting a good understanding of `Promises` and how they work, as well as `async/await` keywords is going to be super useful (and probably essential) in the long run.

This is **UNTESTED**, but should put you on the right path. I'm assuming that your `fetchAge()` function is returning a Promise - i.e. calling an API to retrieve the age - or similar?.

```js
// Since you're only resolving one promise, you don't need `Promise.all`. `fetchAge` returns a promise and so you can chain `then` directly onto it.
// Also, we can `return` the promise here in case you want to do `updateContent().then(...)` later
function updateContent(year, fetchAge) {
    return fetchAge("age")
        .then((data) => {
            // ...
            data = data[0].replace(/{{age}}/g, year);
            $('.mybenifits .content').html(data);
            // ...
        })
        .catch(/* ... */);
}
```

Making the above changes *should* allow you to do the tests like so
Also, since we're testing asynchronous code using `then` chains, you'll want to make sure you use the `done` parameter so that we can tell jest when the test is finished running. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

```js
it('should update the content', (done) => {  
    // ...

    // Since you're mocking a function that returns a promise, your mock function needs to aswell
    function fetchAge(featurename) {
        return Promise.resolve('<p id="fcontent">Current Age is {{age}}</p>');
    }

    updateContent("2020", fetchAge)
      .then(() => {
          console.log("Total html file ="+$('html').html());
          expect($('.mybenifits .content').html()).to.be.equal('<p id="fcontent">Current Age is 2020</p>');
          expect(global.$('.mybenifits .content').html()).to.be.equal('<p id="fcontent">Current Age is 2020</p>');
          done();
      })
      .catch(error => done(e));
});
```

**EDIT**:
Just for your reference, this is a suggestion on how you could rewrite your `updateContent` function using `async/await` (with inline types). Again, not tested locally so may require a tweak or two :)

```js
// Note the `async` keyword
async function updateContent(year: string, fetchAge: () => Promise<string>): Promise<void> {
    // Using async/await, we can now use `try/catch` blocks
    // instead of `<Promise>.catch()`!
    try {
        // Note `await`. Since `fetchAge` returns a Promise, we can `await` it!
        const data = await fetchAge("age");
        const htmlData = data[0].replace(/{{age}}/g, year);
        $('.mybenifits .content').html(htmlData);
    } catch (error) {
        // Add your error handling / logging here
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

And then in your test, you can simply wait for `updateContent` to complete before asserting the DOM values match!

```js
it('should update the content', async () => {
    // ...
    await updateContent("2020", fetchAge);
    expect($('.mybenifits .content').html()).to.be.equal('<p id="fcontent">Current Age is 2020</p>');
    expect(global.$('.mybenifits .content').html()).to.be.equal('<p id="fcontent">Current Age is 2020</p>');
    // ...
});
```